# I want an algorithm to this problem. From a matrix m find the matrix r

Tags: algorithm, matrix

matrix m:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

output: (matrix r)

```
1  3  6
5  12 21
12 27 45
```

How we get the results is:
staring index = (0,0)
for example,

- element at the (1,1) position of the result matrix would be,
  `r[1][1] = m[0][0] + m[0][1] + m[1][0] + m[1][1]`

sum of the elements inside the red box:

[image]

- element at the (2,1) position of the result matrix would be,
  `r[2][1] = matrix[0][0] + m[0][1] + m[1][0] + m[1][1] + m[2][0] + m[2][1]`

sum of the elements inside the red box:

[image]

Comment: That's a good exercise about loops and arrays. Don't seek for help and try to solve it yourself. And try again

Answer (score 1):

One important observation here is that for `i > 0` and `j > 0`:

```
r[i][j] = m[i][j] + r[i-1][j] + r[i][j-1]
                    ^           ^
```

When `i == 0` or `j == 0` then just drop the terms from the above expression that become invalid.

So:

```
r[0][0] = m[0][0]
```

And:

```
r[0][1] = m[0][1] + r[0][0]
```

If you continue with the first row from left to right and then the next rows in the same fashion, you'll always have the information needed to calculate `r[i][j]`.